# Use addWhereExpression function

Tags: views, 8, database

Somehow I am not able to write a query for filtering a view.

I don't understand why the below script is not working:

```
function xxx_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query){
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if($node){
        if($node->getType() === "article"){
            $release_date = $node->get('field_release_date')->value;
            if($release_date){
                $date = new DateTime($release_date, new DateTimeZone(Drupal::config('system.date')->get('timezone')['default']));
                $value = sprintf('%d', $date->getTimestamp() + $date->getOffset());
                $query->addWhereExpression(0, "node__field_release_date.field_release_date_value > 1503944085");
                kint($value);
                //$query->addWhereExpression($this->options['group'], "$field $this->operator $value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that

```
 $query->addWhereExpression('', "node__field_release_date.field_release_date_value > 1503944085");
```

is not formatted correctly. What is this group? Do I need it?

Thanks

Comment: The docs seem pretty clear about what `$group` should be (it would never be an empty string) - is there something in particular you don't understand about it?

Comment: I changed the "" to 0. However Still I am not able to filter for future date. How to format the date value for a query? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: $query->addWhereExpression(0, "node__field_release_date.field_release_date_value > 1535480085");


Should return all nodes with a value for "field_release_date_value" higher than 1535480085. Which is the timestamp. I created nodes with a timestamp of 2020. Still its not possible to collect them .. So I guess its the way to format the query string